# One regular expression to do 0, 1 or n text replacements

Tags: regex

Is it possible to change this text:

`example1 | http://www.example1.com ^ example2 | http://www.example2.com ^ example3 | http://www.example3.com`

into:

`[example1](http://www.example1.com) and [example2](http://www.example2.com) and [example3](http://www.example3.com)`

using *one* single regular expression?

The example contains the name and url of three items, but there can be 0, 1 or n.

So far, I split the string on ^ and then use this regular expression:

search for: `^([^\|]*)\|(.*)$`
replace with: `[\1](\2)`

Afterwards I concatenate the parts into one string.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in one single step.

Comment: What is the regex engine? But I would say no because you need to also replace `^`s with `AND`s.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://regex101.com/r/oSqjsV/1

Comment: The solution of @anubhava will do fine, thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

You can search using regex with 2 capturing groups:

```
([^|\s]+)\s*\|\s*([^^\s]+)(?:\s*\^\s*|$)
```

and replace using:

```
[$1]($2)\n
```

Capture group #1 matches text before `|` and capture group #2 matches text before `^`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oSqjsV/1)